# Вывод элемента списка

Tags: python, list

```
list_ = ['Java', 'Python', 1, 2, 3]

del_name = input('Введите элемент, который хотите удалить  ')
for item in list:
    if item == del_name:
        list.remove(item)
        print('Вы удалили элемент: {0}'.format(item))

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Нельзя называть список словом list, нельзя удалять элементы из списка, по которому идёт итерация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавите `else` к `for` (да, это возможно) и команду `break`:

```
list_ = ['Java', 'Python', 1, 2, 3]

del_name = input('Введите элемент, который хотите удалить  ')
for item in list_:
    if item == del_name:
        list_.remove(item)
        print('Вы удалили элемент: {0}'.format(item))
        break
else:
    print('Введенного значения нет в списке')
```

Команда в `else` выполнится тогда и только тогда, когда цикл `for` исчерпался, т.е. когда не исполнилась команда `break`.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_ = ['Java', 'Python', 1, 2, 3]
del_name = 'Java'
list_.remove(del_name) if del_name in list_ else print('Введенного значения нет в списке')
print(list_)
# ['Python', 1, 2, 3]

list_ = ['Java', 'Python', 1, 2, 3]
del_name = 'Jav'
list_.remove(del_name) if del_name in list_ else print('Введенного значения нет в списке')
print(list_)
# Введенного значения нет в списке
# ['Java', 'Python', 1, 2, 3]

list_ = [item for item in list_ if item != del_name] if del_name in list_ else print(
    'Введенного значения нет в списке')

# ===== Ну или while

list_ = ['Java', 'Python', 1, 2, 3]
del_name = 'Java'

if del_name in list_:
    while del_name in list_:
        list_.remove(del_name)
else:
    print('Введенного значения нет в списке')
```

Comment: Удаляет только первое вхождение, если подходящих элементов несколько, то все последующие остаются.

Comment: @Эникейщик Добавил, хотя не увидел в условии задачи ничего про "все вхождения" справедливости ради нужно отметить я и самого условия не увидел

Answer (score 1):

Другой подход — вместо цикла примените метод списка `.remove()`:

```
if item in list:
    list.remove(item)
    print('Вы удалили элемент: {0}'.format(item))
else:
    print('Введенного значения нет в списке')
```

Между прочим, имя `list` - имя встроенной функции, лучше бы было использовать другое имя, например `list_` (обычно это так делается).